# Hover, mouseover and mouse out

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover

I'm learning and using jQuery and want to display a delete icon for some elements.

I have an outer main div, which contains number of wrappers for elements. Inside the element wrapper, I want to display a delete icon when the user hovers over the element wrapper, and remove it when user moves out of the element wrapper.

Using `mouseover` and `mouseout`, I can display and remove the icon, but as soon as I move my mouse over the delete icon it is removed because it fires the `mouseout` event for the element wrapper.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In a "doh!" moment, I added the missing CSS answer to my answer. You didn't actually say you *had* to do this with JavaScript, did you? :-) But there's a JavaScript option as well (which you'll need if you want IE6 support).

Answer (score 12):

**Two options for you**:

1. CSS's `:hover` pseudo-class (but only if you don't have to support IE6)
2. `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events

#### CSS's `:hover` pseudo-class

You can make the browser do all the work if you don't need IE6 support, by using the [`:hover`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act) pseudo-class:

```
/* Don't show `child` elements inside `parent` elements...*/
parent child {
    display: none;
}

/* ...unless the `parent` element is being hovered over */
parent:hover child {
    display: block; /* or inline-block or whatever */
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/iqihe3)

However, IE6 doesn't support the `:hover` pseudo-class except on `a` elements. IE7+ and all recent other browsers do.

#### `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events

If CSS doesn't do it for you, you're looking for the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, which are IE-specific but emulated by jQuery on all other browsers. jQuery even has a convenient function, [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), for hooking up handlers to both events so you can readily accomplish what you're looking to do.

```
$(...your parent element...).hover(
    function() {
        // Called when the mouse enters the element
    },
    function() {
        // Called when the mouse leaves the element
    }
 );
```

Here's a complete [live example](http://jsbin.com/umalu4):

HTML:

```
<div>Hover over me <span class='del'>[X]</span></div>
<div>And me <span class='del'>[X]</span></div>
<div>And me <span class='del'>[X]</span></div>
```

JavaScript using jQuery:

```
$('div').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).find('span.del').show();
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find('span.del').hide();
  }
);
```

The reason you had trouble with `mouseover` and `mouseout` is that they *bubble*, and so your `mouseout` handler on your parent element was seeing the bubbled `mouseout` from the underlying element when your mouse moved into the delete element. `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` don't bubble, and so they don't have that problem.

Comment: Hey thanks, actually I had used this approach using jquery, but my in my case I want to append the icon on hover. With the above approach, when I move mouse over the icon multiple icons are added to the element wrapper. How to stop this ?

Comment: @KutaPHP: From your description, it sounds like you tried to use `mouseover` and `mouseout` rather than `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. Again, they're different events and they behave differently (see note at the end of the answer above). But if you really were using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, it sounds like you weren't removing the elements on `mouseleave`. Works fine if you do: http://jsbin.com/umalu4/2 But adding to and removing from the DOM is a heavier-weight operation than showing/hiding, recommending showing/hiding.

Comment: Hey thanks again...I fixed this...I was adding image directly, I added it as background to the span and I did it.  :)

Answer (score 3):

have you tried using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply style on the jQuery event onmouseover and onmouseout. When the user hovers over the menu this event will trigger there you can set effects.

```
<style type="text/css">
        .menu {
            background-color: #CDDC39;
            list-style: none;
            margin: 100px;
            padding: 0;
            width: 10em;
        }
            .menu li {
               margin: 0;
               padding: 5px;
           }
            .menu a {
            color: #333;
           }
    </style>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#F44336';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='transparent';" style="background-color: transparent;">
            <a href="http://www.infinetsoft.com/">learn dot net skills</a>
        </li>
        <li onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#F44336';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='transparent';" style="background-color: transparent;">
            <a href="http://www.infinetsoft.com/htmltry">Work out html</a>
        </li>
        <li onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#F44336';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='transparent';" style="background-color: transparent;">
            <a href="http://www.infinetsoft.com/Category/JQuery/9/1">jQuery tutorials</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

[for more details](http://www.infinetsoft.com/Post/How-to-create-menu-hover-effect-using-onmouseover-and-onmouseout-in-JQuery/1212)