# When a marker lies behind open infobox - Event mouseover with InfoBox plugin Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm having trouble with v3 of the Google Maps API and using the InfoBox plugin specifically with respect to this usability issue use case:

Since my map requires a custom infobox to be opened upon hovering the mouse over each respective marker, when the map has 2 markers on it that are close in proximity, even when/if one of the markers lies behind an infobox that is currently open after hovering the other close-by marker, it is triggered when mousing over it marker (even though it's behind the currently open infobox) and the other infobox obstructs the currently/previously opened infobox

I've followed the question and answer process by another poster here: [Google Maps API v3 Event mouseover with InfoBox plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429444/google-maps-api-v3-event-mouseover-with-infobox-plugin) and have followed the recommended code, but i can't wrap my mind around how to prevent markers that lie BEHIND an open infobox to not be triggered until that infobox is closed.

```
var gpoints = [];

function initializeMap1() {

    var Map1MileLatLang = new google.maps.LatLng(39.285900,-76.570000);
    var Map1MileOptions = {
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [ 'Styled']
        },
       mapTypeControl: false,
        zoom: 14,
      center: Map1MileLatLang,
      //mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
      mapTypeId: 'Styled' 
    };
    var Map1Mile = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), Map1MileOptions);
    var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: 'Styled' });//new
    Map1Mile.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapType);//new

   for ( var i=0; i<5; i++ ) {
            gpoints.push( new point(Map1Mile) );
            gpoints.push( new point2(Map1Mile) );
   }

function popup(_point) {
        _point.popup = new InfoBox({
            content:            _point.content,
            pane:               'floatPane',
            closeBoxURL:        '',
            alignBottom:        1
        });

        _point.popup.open(_point.marker.map, _point.marker);

            google.maps.event.addListener(_point.popup, 'domready', function() {
            //Have to put this within the domready or else it can't find the div element (it's null until the InfoBox is opened)

                $(_point.popup.div_).hover(
                    function() {
                        //This is called when the mouse enters the element
                    },
                    function() {
                        //This is called when the mouse leaves the element
                        _point.popup.close();
                    }
                );
            });  

   }

 function point(_map) {
        this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:           new google.maps.LatLng(39.291003,-76.546234),
            map:                _map
        });

        this.content = '<div class="map-popup" style="width:100px;"><div class="map-popup-window"><div class="map-popup-content"><a href="http://www.google.com/">Just try to click me!</a><br/>Hovering over this text will result in a <code>mouseout</code> event firing on the <code>map-popup</code> element and this will disappear.</div></div>';

        // Scope
        var gpoint = this;

        // Events
        google.maps.event.addListener(gpoint.marker, 'mouseover', function() {
            popup(gpoint);
    });

    }



 function point2(_map) {
        this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:           new google.maps.LatLng(39.295003,-76.545234),
            map:                _map
        });

        this.content = '<div class="map-popup" style="width:100px;"><div class="map-popup-window"><div class="map-popup-content"><a href="http://www.google.com/">Just try to click me!</a><br/>Hovering over this text will result in a <code>mouseout</code> event firing on the <code>map-popup</code> element and this will disappear.</div></div>';

        // Scope
        var gpoint = this;

        // Events
        google.maps.event.addListener(gpoint.marker, 'mouseover', function() {
            popup(gpoint);
        });
    }
```

After doing experimenting, i suspect this issue is irrelevant to z-index... am i correct in understanding this needs to be caught in the javascript?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Adding **optimized: false** attribute for your markers should solve the problem.

```
this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:           new google.maps.LatLng(39.295003,-76.545234),
        map:                _map,
        optimized:          false
    });
```