# Google maps API marker - mouseover instead of click - using kml

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, mouseover, marker

I wanna simply get markers from a kml file and show them on a map, but add "mouseover" for tooltip, not click

using this code, but it don't work (works if i use click)

```
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.477876, -2.471289);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 5,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    //kml begin
    var nyLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://code.nebtron.com/kml2.kml', {suppressInfoWindows: false});
    nyLayer.setMap(map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(nyLayer, "mouseover", function(kmlEvent) {
      var text = kmlEvent.featureData.description;
      showInDiv(text);
    });

    function showInDiv(text) {
      var sidediv = document.getElementById('contentWindow');
      sidediv.innerHTML = text;
    }//kml end

  }
```

Demo: http://code.nebtron.com/map3.php

Comment: You should try the approach [in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429444/google-maps-api-v3-event-mouseover-with-infobox-plugin).


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429444/google-maps-api-v3-event-mouseover-with-infobox-plugin

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11003812/1331671), there is no `mouseover` event for `KMLLayers`. But maybe you could use a `polygon`. Here's a [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon).

Hope this helps!