# Why is onMouseOver event fired when the mouse only moves into an inner element?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, onmouseover, onmouseout

When the mouse hovers into the inner element, the `mouseOut` event for the outer element is fired first, then the `mouseOver` element for inner element is fired, then the `mouseOver` element for the inner element is fired last.

Why does this happen? Because the inner element technically is still inside of the outer element, so the mouse doesn't leave the outer element when it moves into the inner element. Is there a way to prevent that?

Full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/pMCeu/4/

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this you should use mouseenter and mouseleave instead of mouseover and mouseout.

It is due to event bubbling. take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463376/hover-mouseover-and-mouse-out) post for a little more info.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the solution above is correct and complete.
but you can also use mousemove event