# Jquery.Hover not working for dynamic Element

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, hover

Here is my code

```
$(".inboxfeedlist li").hover(function(e){alert('');}
```

This is not working for dynamically created elements, even i have use

```
$(".inboxfeedlist li").bind('hover',function(){})
```

is also not working, what's problem with code.

Comment: Can you simulate your situation as closely as possible on http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`live` become deprecated at jQuery 1.9. We can use `on` with `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events instead:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".save-btn", function(e) {
    $(this).css("background-image","url('ie/imgs/btn/hover-btn.png')");
    $(this).find("a").css("background-image","url('ie/imgs/btn/hover-btn-left.png')");
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", ".save-btn", function(e) {
    $(this).css("background-image","url('ie/imgs/btn/btn.png')");
    $(this).find("a").css("background-image","url('ie/imgs/btn/btn-left.png')");
});
```

For some reason I can't use `hover` with `on`. It simply doesn't work. But, from what I have read, hover is just an adaptation from mouseenter and mouseleave, so it is fine. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4463384/1031340)

If you do not need to support IE6, I recommend you use `:hover` on your CSS (if it is a change only in CSS, how example above).

Comment: It's important to use "on" event on the element that wasn't dynamicly changed.

Comment: In some cases where we want to show/hide stuff, mouseenter/mouseleave combination works better for me

Comment: mouseover isn't the proper syntax, mouseenter should be used: http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes

Answer (score 3):

try [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$(".inboxfeedlist li").live('hover',function(){});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the live method:

```
$(".inboxfeedlist li").live('hover', function(e){alert('');});
```

A side note [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) does take two callback functions, did you mean `mouseover`

Comment: you learn something new everyday..., still wondering what the use case for this would be? Did not have a problem yet, that would have required this.

Comment: I use it for when I toggle something like in `$(".menu li").hover(function(){$(".submenu",this).toggle()})`.  Because toggle depends on the current state of the element, it can be used for the hover over and the hover out.

Comment: Why does `.live('hover' ...` works but not `.hover` on a dynamic element?

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live(). https://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 1):

Use `delegate` or `live` to bind the events. This will make sure anything added dynamically will be bound to the event handler as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). Delegate is prefered

```
$(document.body).delegate(".inboxfeedlist li", "hover", function(){
        alert('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.inboxfeedlist li').live('hover', function(e) { alert(''); });
```

[jQuery live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

[jQuery delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
$(document).on('mouseover','div.cover-wrapper',function(){
    $(this).css({'border':'1px solid #000'});
});


$(document).on('mouseout','div.cover-wrapper',function(){
    $(this).css({'border':'none'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the use and details of these functions

http://api.jquery.com/live/

$( selector ).live( events, data, handler );                // jQuery 1.3+

$( document ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );  // jQuery 1.4.3+

$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+