# Targeting with "this" on dynamically loading <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div in which an unordered list is being loaded into, dynamically.  First, let me say that when the ul is hardcoded in, it works perfectly, the problem occurs when a new ul is *loaded*. Here's my javascript:

```
$('#products ul li').hover(function(){
   $(this).find(".productDesc").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

The html of the code that is dynamically loaded into `<div id='products'></div>` is structured like so:

```
<ul id='category1'> 
  <li>
     <p class='productDesc'>description 1 here</p>
  </li>

  <li>
     <p class='productDesc'>description 2 here</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The problem lies in "`this`". When the new UL is dynamically loaded, "`this`" no longer seems to refer to the element I'm hovering on. Instead, it seems to refer to nothing at all. What can I do to make "`this`" work properly?

Comment: insert the first code after your ajax code and then attach the listeners...

Comment: Delegate the hover to #product

Comment: add the live event for the hover.

Comment: If the event is triggered for the dynamically loaded elements, then this will refer to the correct li element. It cannot refer to "nothing". So, is the handler actually triggered?

Comment: you need to look at [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and mouseenter and mouseleave events

Comment: @FelixKling looks like the `ul li` are dynamically loaded the mouseenter and leave events are not fired

Comment: @arun, most likely, still want to verify that, since the OP didn't explicitly say that the handler is not called.

Comment: @FelixKling `The problem lies in "this". When the new UL is dynamically loaded` - I think it is clear from that

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/q/7972389/218196 and [potentially more](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+dynamic+element+hover).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) since `li` the elements are added dynamically.

Since you are using [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), there is no hover event - it is a utility method to register both [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events

```
$('#products').on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'ul li', function () {
    $(this).find(".productDesc").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: OP could also bind directly to the elements as they're created, which is sometimes more desirable than delegation for events that fire repeatedly, like `mouseenter/leave`.

Comment: Yes, that's it! I don't really understand the theory behind it, but it definitely fixed the problem.  What about the .delegate method on jp310's answer? How are they different?

Comment: @user2755541 there is not much difference... `.on()` is the new method (>=1.7) where as delegate is there from 1.4.2... but new codes the recommended method is `on`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#products').delegate('ul li','hover', function( event ) {
    if( event.type === 'mouseenter' )  
        //your code here 
    else
        //your code here  
});
```